# Protecting superclass method from subclass method

Tags: java, class, inheritance, methods

Is it possible to a class has a method that can only be called by it's objects and hidden for a subclass object? For instance:

```
class ClassOne {
    ... // attributes

    public void doSomething() { ... }
}

class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
    ... // attributes and methods
}

ClassOne c1 = new ClassOne();
c1.doSomething(); // ok to call

ClassTwo c2 = new ClassTwo();
c2.doSomething(); // forbidden
```

I know this seems weird thinking in therms of inheritance, but is it possible?

*PS: the objective of this question is just to learn more about inheritance of OO programming.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible and your right that this would break inheritance. Think about

```
ClassOne c2 = new ClassTwo();
c2.doSomething(); // what to do?
```

This has to work because ClassTwo [is a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) ClassOne. Edit: at least is has to compile, if the method is overridden and does something else is up to your design. But you cannot make the compiler produce an error on this.

Answer (score 3):

Since doSomething is declared in classOne it will be available in any subclasses. You can't hide it or reduce it's visibility ( make it private or protected ). Since ClassTwo is a ClassOne it can do everything ClassOne can do.

The closest you can come is something like :

```
class ClassTwo extends ClassOne {
   public void doSomething() { throw new UnsupportedOperationException(); }
}
```

which doesn't quite do what you want.

If you're in a situation where you need to do this best is probably to rethink the class hierarchy into types of your class that have the doSomething method and types that don't

```
public class Parent { ... }
public class ClassOne extends Parent {
   public void doSomething(){ ... }
}
public class ClassTwo extends Parent { 
}
```

or put doSomething in an interface.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I don't need to implement. I'm just curious about this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

May be I misunderstood you, but why don't you just make your method private or package visible?

Comment: If the method is marked private, we can't call the method using a super-class reference (except if the code is in the same class).

Comment: but in the question there is no word about calling through superclass variable. I guess it's just mistake in example.